# Can ViewModel implement LifecycleOwner?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, lifecycleowner

I know that, `ViewModel`s should never keep a reference to a `LifecycleOwner` since it keeps a reference to a context and hence this causes a memory leak. But my question is, can I implement a `LifecyclerOwner` for `ViewModel` itself? with two valid callbacks, `onCreate()` triggered when view model's constructor is invoked and `onDestroy()` triggered when view model's `onCleared()` is invoked. Since `LifecycleOwner` is just an Java interface, I think this will not cause any memory leak. But to be on safer side, I'm asking this.

Comment: `Since LifecycleOwner is just an Java interface` - Yes its just an interface, read the interface contract. `I think this will not cause any memory leak` - I think you are conflating historical Android issues around memory leaks, caused by strong references and just implementing an observer pattern.  Look at `Lifecycle`, `LifecycleOwner` & `LifecycleObserver` for completion of the the Android pattern.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the goal is here, since the constructor runs when the ViewModel is created and onClear runs when the ViewModel is destroyed could you run the desired code in each of those methods?

Comment: @shawn yes, i can do that. But attaching multiple listeners to firebase database and storing a reference to each of them in view model just to detach those listeners in the end got a bit messy. Previously, when I was not using view models, I wrote an lifecycle aware component, that attaches listeners and detaches them automatically when the activity ondestroy was called. So I wanted to implement the same here.

Comment: TL; DR: wanna reduce some repetitive lines of code in view model.

Comment: What about using coroutines, in onClear() you would be able to cancel the SupervisorJob().

Comment: viewModelScope is there.. But canceling a job stops our app from listening. But does that remove attached listeners from firebase database? I think we should explicitly remove them by calling `removeEventListener`. I will check that. Thanks.

Comment: @Shawn cancelling coroutines has to be co-operative. Coroutines is just a library and is really an implemtation of an observer or pub/sub pattern.  A better approach would be, if you're getting into talking about using external libraries is `Flow` - more specfically a `channelFlow` that can suspend and perform "clean up" lambda - `awaitclose { // remove listener invoked when scope is cancelled }` when either the job or scope is cancelled.  Its "kind of" an equivilent of an Emitter in RxJava.